# Nginx try_files ignore path

Tags: nginx

I have a location setup for images like:

```
location ~* ^/images/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
   try_files /disk/$uri /images?uri=$uri;
}
```

The `$uri` includes the `images` name.  When I access `/images/one/two/three/item.jpg`, I want to exclude the `images` from the try_files.  So accessing this should actually be trying `/disk/one/two/three/item.jpg`.

Any idea how I can exclude this first segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would wrap the regex location with a prefix location. This isolates the regex location and keeps it from conflicting with others. Your config will scale more smoothly as a result.

If there will only be images in this directory, then it's simpler to capture everything after /images/ and not worry about the file extension. You're then free to have a case sensitive match which is a little quicker.

```
location /images/ {
    location ~ ^/images/(?<img_path>.+) {
        try_files /disk/$img_path /images?uri=$img_path;
    }
}
```